# HandleAuthenticateAsync is called more than once

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

When I try to connect to a SignalR hub the `HandleAuthenticateAsync()` method in the `AuthenticationHandler` it is called twice by the .net client and 3 times by another client.

But when I call an http method, the handler is invoked once only.

this is my `ConfigureServices()` in `Startup`

```
        services.AddAuthentication(FbigAuthenticationHandler.PROVIDER_NAME)
        .AddScheme<FbigAuthenticationSchemeOptions, FbigAuthenticationHandler>(FbigAuthenticationHandler.PROVIDER_NAME, null);

        services.AddCors();
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSignalR(options =>
        {
            options.AddFilter<BadUserInputFilter>();
            options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1); //change this in production
        });


        services.AddHangfire(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
                .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
                .UseMemoryStorage()
                .WithJobExpirationTimeout(TimeSpan.FromHours(3))
                .UseDefaultTypeSerializer();
        });

        services.AddHangfireServer();
```

and `Configure()`

```
        app.UseCors(builder => builder
               .AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
           );

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoint => endpoint.MapHub<MasterHub>("/connect"));

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, SignalR makes a minimum of 2 requests, one for the `/<hubname>/negotiate` endpoint and another for the `/<hubname>` endpoint. In order to have one request only, you can specify WebSockets and skip negotiate in the client options. (The caveat is that environments without websockets wont work, and that you can't use the Azure SignalR service)

Comment: I am skipping the by the client now, but what if I want to negotiate, will it be ok to return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket) when I find it negotiation request? because I can't handle authentication twice as it talk to another api to validate a token for once